# Reading/Converting PIPE delimited txt file using VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, csv, uipath, uipath-studio

I have a pipe delimited file with an extension txt. I am using UiPath invoke code (basically I am using VB.net coding) to either read the file into a datatable variable. While Uipath has inbuilt activities to read CSV files, it doesn't work for many rows. I tried with few rows (about 10-20) and it works, but for about 1000-2000 rows, it gives me error that CSV file format in invalid. I am looking for a VB function to either convert the Pipe delimited txt file to a workbook xlsx file. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you examined the file to see if there is an invalid line?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter which file extention (TXT/CSV/...) it is. The steps to solve your issue are simple:

1. Use the **Read CSV** activity
2. Set the path of the file here
3. [image: Read CSV]
4. Here you set the **Delimiter** to your **Pipe**